# Globals in business process

Tags: drools, jbpm

Where do you initialize a global value in the business process. Suppose I wanted a counter every time a process is created. I know I can create it and increment it using setGlobal("count", count+1). But where do you specify the initial value?

Answer (score 1):

Inside a process script, you can do something like:
jBPM6: kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal(..)
jBPM5: kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal(..)

Comment: what's the difference between "globals" and "process variables"

Answer (score 0):

When you start your app you can do something like ksession.setGlobal("count", 0);

Comment: you can't right now.. but it sounds as a good community contribution.. contact me if you want some guidance.. it shouldn't be so difficult to implement